# Decompile and edit multiple interdependent jar files

Tags: jar, java

Hey I am new to java and trying to learn it. I have learned the best way it to learn is by reading and seeing how are other software are working and then implement a better way in my own app. So i have started decompiling 
I already know jd-gui and used it to decomppile or edit jar files. But now i have multiple jar files and they are interdependent, I tried to google but could not find anything good. Help would be great. 


Main question. How to edit or decompile multiple interdependent jar files.

I am not trying to do anything illegal or wrong just want to learn

Comment: Start with source, not JARs.

Comment: means..?? 
i have like 20 jar files in app ... and when i try to edit one it says error...